# XSD elements inside a recursive defined element

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am facing an issue with an `XML Schema`. I would like to introduce `elements` into another `element` which has been defined to be recursive.

The above lines of code are meant to represent file and folders.

Here is the current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1"> 

    <xs:complexType name="folder_type">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="folder" type="folder_type"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="filefoldertree">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="folder" type="folder_type"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

For instance, the above `XSD` code allows me to define the following `XML` lines:

```
<filefoldertree xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:/C:/Users/Hadi/Desktop/filefoldertree.xsd">

    <folder name="a">
        <folder name="b">
            <folder name="c">
            </folder>
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="d">
    </folder>
</filefoldertree>
```

Until there, this is a desirable behavior. However I would like to add a sequence of `file` `elements`, nested in the `folder` one. For example, I am seeking for the following result:

```
    <folder name="a">
        <folder name="b">
            <file attr1="x" attr2="y" attr3="z"></file>
            <folder name="c">
                <file attr1="x" attr2="y" attr3="z"></file>
            </folder>
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="d">
        <file attr1="x" attr2="y" attr3="z"></file>
    </folder>
    <file attr1="x" attr2="y" attr3="z"></file>
```

Since `folder` is a `typed` `element`, I cannot define a nested `complextype`, however I need its recursive functionality.

How to modify the `XSD` code in order to achieve the behavior illustrated by the code above?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xs:choice` in a recursive type declaration as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="filefoldertree" type="FolderType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="FolderType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="folder" type="FolderType"/>
      <xs:element name="file" type="FileType"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="FileType">
    <xs:sequence/>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Note: You might want to name the top-level element `folder` rather than the one-off, `filefoldertree`.

Comment: Oh, right, files can't contain folders.  Better have a separate type for `file` then... Fixed.  Thanks for pointing that out.